# SQL blank rows between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, sql-order-by

I am trying to output a blank row after each row.

For example:

```
SELECT id,job,amount FROM table

+----+-----+--------+
| id | job | amount |
+----+-----+--------+
|  1 | 100 |    123 |
|  2 | 200 |    321 |
|  3 | 300 |    421 |
+----+-----+--------+
```

To the following:

```
+----+-----+--------+
| id | job | amount |
+----+-----+--------+
|  1 | 100 |    123 |
|    |     |        |
|  2 | 200 |    321 |
|    |     |        |
|  3 | 300 |    421 |
+----+-----+--------+
```

I know I can do similar things with a UNION like:

```
SELECT null AS id, null AS job, null AS amount
UNION
SELECT id,job,amount FROM table
```

Which would give me a blank row at the beginning, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it every second row. A nested SELECT/UNION? - Have tried but nothing seemed to work.

The DBMS is SQL Server 2016

Comment: Why do you want to that? In general, this type of data display issue is better handled on application side.

Comment: I second @GMB. That sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Anyway, please [edit] the question and add a tag for the DBMS you're using and state which column defines the order. Probably `id`?

Comment: It's for an integration, which one side for whatever reason requires blank lines. I have no ability to capture the data and modify it outside of the SQL query. It's a direct connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an akward requirement, that would most probably better handled on application side. Here is, however, one way to do it:

```
select id, job, amount
from (
    select id, job, amount, id order_by from mytable
    union all 
    select null, null, null, id from mytable
) t
order by order_by, id desc
```

The trick is to add an additional column to the `union`ed query, that keeps track of the original `id`, and can be used to sort the records in the outer query. You can then use `id desc` as second sorting criteria, which will put `null` values in second position.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=279896f2d2d1ccd1196a76dd5457f634)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 1 id, 100 job, 123 amount
    union all select 2, 200, 321
    union all select 3, 300, 421
)
select id, job, amount
from (
    select id, job, amount, id order_by from mytable
    union all 
    select null, null, null, id from mytable
) t
order by order_by, id desc;
```

```
  id |  job | amount
---: | ---: | -----:
   1 |  100 |    123
null | null |   null
   2 |  200 |    321
null | null |   null
   3 |  300 |    421
null | null |   null
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can just use `apply`:

```
select v.id, v.job, v.amount
from t cross apply
     (values (id, job, amount, id, 1),
             (null, null, null, id, 2)
     ) v(id, job, amount, ord1, ord2)
order by ord1, ord2;
```